# GWT Designer and Cell Widgets for Performance

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-designer

After watching [this Google I/O video on GWT performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y) it is obvious that the GWT team wants developers to embrace the so-called "Cell Widgets" over normal (clunkier, slower) widgets.

I'm new to GWT and am using GWT Designer to help acclimate me better and learn the API.  In the GWT Designer palette, there is a section for Cell Widgets, however the selection to choose from is greatly restricted. For instance, if I want to end up with an HTML password field, my only option is `PasswordTextBox` from the normal (non-Cell) widget pane. There is no Cell-equivalent such as `CellPasswordTextBox`.

Is this because of some short-coming of GWT Designer? You'd think that if Google was promoting this Cell Widget "library" they'd have Cell-equivalents for every widget type. Is this not the case? Do developers *have* to deal with non-Cell widgets at some point? Just confused because it seems like I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the relevant part of that Google I/O link is 8:50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole concept of the cell widgets is to make your own. There is no good intergration with the Designer - though I think there is some - but when you reach the level that enables you to write the custom Cell widgets you will not need it anyway.

Look [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells) for further details.

A showcase with corresponding codes can be found [here](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox)

Comment: See also general [UiCellWidgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#available)